# I would love to shorten up this while loop in Java. Any tips on how I should do this?

Tags: java, while-loop

```
while (head <= tail) {
        if (Choice == possibleNumbers[(head + tail)/2]) {
            foundNumber = true;
            break;
        }
        else if (Choice < possibleNumbers[(head + tail)/2]) {
            tail = (head + tail)/2 - 1;
        }
        else
            head = (head + tail)/2 + 1;
    }
    return foundNumber;
}
```

This is part of a number searcher lab I did in class.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because review requests for working code should go to codereview.stackexchange.com

Comment: [Java naming convention](http://stackoverflow.com/documentation/java/2697/oracle-official-code-standard/9031/naming-conventions#t=201611210634432178081) says that `Choice` should be named `choice`.

Comment: the issue isn't really formatting as much as it is a violation. I am supposed to clean it up and apply Clean Code. I have a complex computation inside of a conditional, which is a violation of Clean Code. How do i make it not so complex?

Answer (score 2):

If you're worried about the length of the code, I'd suggest favouring clarity over brevity.  Code it communication, and it's more important that your code is readable and extensible than that it be short.

If this was production code, I'd say use a library method - I think this is equivalent to [`Arrays.binarySearch`](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/util/arrays_binarysearch_int.htm), but looks like you're doing it as an exercise.

One code style change I'd suggest - `break` can make loop logic harder to follow.  If you changed the condition to `while (head <= tail && !foundNumber)` then you could remove that.

Comment: First paragraph is gold.